# Create vector which ascends based on repeated values of another vector (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, vector, repeat

Here's a relatively simply one. Let's say I have the following vector ('V1'):

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
```

I want to create a second vector, V2, which starts at 1 and increases for each iteration of a value in V1, but then resets at a new value of V1. So for instance:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
1
2
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
```

There may be a single iteration of a value in V1, or as many as 6.

The solution might use a for loop, but I imagine there is a simpler form without needing a loop ('repmat' comes to mind).

Comment: Should we assume `V1` is sorted?

Comment: If you can do it without a loop then even better. And yes, V1 is sorted.

Comment: Are there ever gaps greater than 1 (i.e. missing numbers, like `V1 = [1; 1; 1; 3; 3; 3; 4; 4];`)?

Comment: No there aren't any gaps. The values ascend by a constant (e.g., 1). Non-incremental values are a problem for another day!

Comment: Well, good news! The non-incremental value problem appears to be solved already by all the solutions below. ;)

Comment: I was hoping the number of likes would dictate which answer should get accepted, but they're all pretty equal!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `V1` is sorted, here's a vectorized solution using [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
V2 = accumarray(V1, 1, [], @(x) {1:numel(x)});
V2 = [V2{:}].';
```

Answer (score 6):

Another suggestion without a loop.

First count the number of repeated values

```
a=histc(v1,unique(v1));
```

Construct counting array

```
b = ones(1,sum(a));
```

Now counter the cumulated sum the appropriate places:

```
a = a(1:end-1);
b(cumsum(a)+1) = b(cumsum(a)+1) - a;
```

finally take the cumulated sum

```
cumsum(b)
```

In total

```
v1 = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4];
a=histcounts(v1,[unique(v1),inf]);
b = ones(1,sum(a));
a = a(1:end-1);
b(cumsum(a)+1) = b(cumsum(a)+1) - a;
disp(cumsum(b))
```

**TIMEITs:**

Running on random sorted input `V1 = sort(randi(100,1e6,1));` I obtain the following timings in Matlab 2017a.

- Gnovic's first suggestion: 2.852872e-02
- Gnovic's second suggestion: 2.909344e-02
- AVK's suggestion: 3.935982e-01
- RadioJava's suggestion: 2.441206e-02
- Nicky's suggestion: 9.153147e-03

Code for reference:

```
function [] = SO()
V1 = sort(randi(100,1e6,1));

t1 = timeit(@() gnovice1(V1)); fprintf("* Gnovic's first suggestion: %d\n",t1);
t2 = timeit(@() gnovice2(V1)); fprintf("* Gnovic's second suggestion: %d\n",t2);
t3 = timeit(@() AVK(V1)); fprintf("* AVK's suggestion: %d\n",t3);
t4 = timeit(@() RadioJava(V1)); fprintf("* RadioJava's suggestion: %d\n",t4);
t5 = timeit(@() Nicky(V1)); fprintf("* Nicky's suggestion: %d\n",t5);


function []=gnovice1(V1)
V2 = accumarray(V1, 1, [], @(x) {1:numel(x)});
V2 = [V2{:}].';

function []=gnovice2(V1)
V2 = ones(size(V1));
V2([find(diff(V1))+1; end]) = 1-accumarray(V1, 1);
V2 = cumsum(V2(1:end-1));

function []=AVK(v)
a= v;
for i=unique(v)'
    a(v==i)= 1:length(a(v==i));
end

function []=RadioJava(vec)
vec = vec(:).';
zero_separated=[1,vec(1:end-1)==vec(2:end)];
c=cumsum(zero_separated);
zeros_ind = ~zero_separated;
d = diff([1 c(zeros_ind)]);
zero_separated(zeros_ind) = -d;
output=cumsum(zero_separated);

function []=Nicky(v1)
v1 = v1(:).';
a=histcounts(v1,[unique(v1),inf]);
b = ones(1,sum(a));
a = a(1:end-1);
b(cumsum(a)+1) = b(cumsum(a)+1) - a;
b = cumsum(b);
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the second approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49699191/2586922):

```
t = diff([0; find([diff(V1)~=0; true])]);
V2 = ones(sum(t), 1);
V2(cumsum(t(1:end-1))+1) = 1-t(1:end-1);
V2 = cumsum(V2);
```

Answer (score 3):

## Solution without a loop

```
vec =[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3];    
zero_separated=[1,vec(1:end-1)==vec(2:end)]; % 0 at every new set    
c=cumsum(zero_separated); % Temporary cumsum    
zeros_ind = ~zero_separated;    
d = diff([1 c(zeros_ind)]); % deltas in the temporary cumsum
zero_separated(zeros_ind) = -d; % Set zeros ind to delta    
output=cumsum(zero_separated); % Calculate cumsum now
```

## Output

```
output = 1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995399/matlab-cumsum-reset-at-nan)

Comment: So something like: >> zero_separated(isnan(zero_separated)) = 1-diff([0 find(isnan(zero_separated))]); >> cumsum(zero_separated)...which works, but ideally the smallest number would be 1 not 0

Comment: fixed and a better and simpler solution

Answer (score 2):

```
v = [1;1;1;2;2;2;2;3;3;4;4;4;4;5;5;5];
a= v;
for i=unique(v)'
    a(v==i)= 1:length(a(v==i));
end
disp(a)
```